# Check database access (SQL Server 2005 / 2008)

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connectivity

What is the best way to check database access from remote machine.

Here is the situation:

- SQL Server 2005 (or 2008) is running on `MACHINE1` (Windows 2003 or 2008). There is a database called `ENTERPRISEDB`.
- Another server, called `MACHINE2` (Windows 2003 or 2008). It has ODBC connection to `MACHINE1`.

Now, what is the best and simplest SQL query to check if `MACHINE2` can connect and access the `ENTERPRISEDB` in `MACHINE1`?

Thanks.

Comment: **It's important to accept answers!**.  You have asked 5 questions and cast no votes and accepted no answers.  Make sure you accept the correct answer to  your question so others know what works.

Comment: Silly me, I did not know how to accept answer! I tried to click the make useful, but got warning. Thanks! I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ODBC connection is to database ENTERPRISEDB then you could run

```
SELECT top 1 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE CATALOG_NAME='ENTERPRISEDB'
```

which will return "1" if the database exists or nothing if it doesn't.

If you need a boolean/int return then try

```
SELECT case when COUNT(*) >0 then 1 else 0 end 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE CATALOG_NAME='ENTERPRISEDB'
```

which will return "1" if it exists, "0" if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I always use

```
Select @@servername, @@SERVICENAME
```

Returns Server Name, Instance Name to check basic server connection. To check database connectivity itself is correct you can't beat sys.objects.

```
select DB_NAME(), * from sys.objects
```

Returns a table with current database name as the first column and a list of object names as the general data list.